# Why my libgdx extended Image() show me nothing on screen, when standard Image() work as expected?

Tags: android, image, animation, kotlin, libgdx

I'm trying extend libgdx `Image()` class uses adding `Animation()` functionality.
Finally animation show nothing on screen, but frame names changed as expected. In same time standard libgdx `Image()` work as expected(i can see it on screen in correct position+can see debug green frame).

How fix it?

This is Kotlin code. Code is short, and i can't found any bad places. Web search show me nothing good for my case. And no good(completely working) examples, which i can recode etc.

github link to extended `Image()` class, named `ImageAnimationTextureRegion.kt`. Possibly bad place inside this class, but i am not sure.
https://github.com/3dformortals/demo-libgdx/blob/master/DemoAnimation/core/src/animated/ImageAnimationTextureRegion.kt

github link to animated human class, template for player, named `AnimatedHumanTextureRegion.kt`
https://github.com/3dformortals/demo-libgdx/blob/master/DemoAnimation/core/src/animated/AnimatedHumanTextureRegion.kt

github link to main menu screen, named `MainMenuScreen.kt`, which is libgdx `Stage()` instance parent object
https://github.com/3dformortals/demo-libgdx/blob/master/DemoAnimation/core/src/com/kda/MainMenuScreen.kt

full project link on github, can be executed uses intellij IDEA
https://github.com/3dformortals/demo-libgdx/tree/master/DemoAnimation

How can i fix it?
Or may be have better way to do player object with at least next functionality:
- can be added and rendered on screen as libgdx Stage() child , uses `stage.addActor(aniimage)` etc
- offset x y
- few animations(if possible inside player object), which can be switched inside `MainMenuScreen.kt` render method

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work, but I think you could draw the drawable to the batch yourself by extending Actor instead of Image. If the problem comes from Image it will be solved. Since you only need the drawing part (not scaling modes) there's no point in using Image.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into your code and found a bug.

You said that standard `Image` class works, but your inheritor doesn't. It happens because you set `drawable` to them in different ways. For `Image` you use constructor, that automatically sets it's size, see:

```
/** One of constructors called from other */
    public Image (Drawable drawable, Scaling scaling, int align) {
        setDrawable(drawable);
        this.scaling = scaling;
        this.align = align;
        setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight()); // see
    }
```

But when you use empty constructor and set drawable manually, the size stays zero.

So the solution is to set it in `ImageAnimationTextureRegion` in `act()`:

```
override fun act(delta: Float) {
     if (..) {
        val frame = this.animation!!.getKeyFrame(time, true)
        drawable = TextureRegionDrawable(frame)
        setSize(prefWidth, prefHeight)
     }
```

I saw some of your code. You write on Kotlin like on Java, it has many useful methods in standard library that you don't use. You use `null-safety` in wrong way. 
Don't write `this` keyword everywhere, it's used for other things, read about this.

Btw, There is nice book about Kotlin on Russian - "Котлин в действии".

Comment: finally i solve the problem uses Drawables vs TextureRegions way, with saving/rebuilding stripWhiteSpaceXY from textureAtlas. But code now much different. The hole was i have no `this.pack()` after `setDrawable()` of Image. TextureRegion way work too but whiteSpaces is broken. And `setSize` no need because it automatically will be set later when animation started.